# Remove margin on MessageBubbleTopLabel in JSQMessageViewController

Tags: ios, margin, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I have a slight problem with my sub-classed JSQMessagesViewController. I would like to remove the margin of the MessageBubbleTopLabel to the right for outgoing messages, and the left for incoming messages, so the text is aligned with the text within the bubble.

I have tried to change the JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout of the collectionViewController, but this didn't change anything.

[image: Message View Controller]